# Привильный ли запрос в базу данных?

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день!

Нужно обновить сразу несколько таблиц, вставить id туда, где имя = имя,

Я делал следующим образом:

```
UPDATE fund_people, shop_info, volun_db, adopt_db
  SET shop_info.shelter_id = '2',
  fund_people.shelter_id = '2',
  volun_db.shelter_id = '2',
  adopt_db.shelter_id = '2'
 WHERE fund_people.shelter = 'Pesaleidja (Estonia)'
  AND shop_info.shelter = 'Pesaleidja (Estonia)'
  AND volun_db.shelter_name = 'Pesaleidja (Estonia)'
  AND adopt_db.shelter_name = 'Pesaleidja (Estonia)'
```

ошибок никаких не выдает, но и не обновляет таблицу, если обновлять по одной таблице, то все ок:

```
UPDATE shop_info SET shelter_id = '2' WHERE shelter = 'Pesaleidja (Estonia)'
```

Так вот вопрос, где у меня ошибка? И как правильно поставить запрос, чтобы обновить сразу несколько таблиц?

Comment: Используйте несколько UDPATE запросов.

Comment: Это вариант конечно, но хотелось бы одним обойтись и заодно понять почему не работает мой вариант

Comment: не, ну так то можно...... если напрямую запрос в phpmyadmin или подобной оболочке произвести - он выполнится? Если да, то проблема в php коде. Если нет, то наверняка оболочка скажет где ошибка

Comment: Да, пробовал напрямую запрос в phpmyadmin, он как бы выполняется, все проходит успешно, но таблицы не обновляется ), вот такой вот парадокс

Comment: Попробуйте указать условия связывания таблиц и отбора в секции _table_reference_, а не в секции WHERE.

Comment: Может быть попробовать вместо объединяющего AND в условии WHERE прописать выбор условия OR

Answer (score 0):

```
  UPDATE fund_people, shop_info, volun_db, adopt_db
  SET 
      shop_info.shelter_id = '2',
      fund_people.shelter_id = '2',
      volun_db.shelter_id = '2',
      adopt_db.shelter_id = '2'

 WHERE 
      fund_people.shelter = shop_info.shelter AND
      shop_info.shelter = volun_db.shelter_name AND
      volun_db.shelter_name = adopt_db.shelter_name AND
      fund_people.shelter = 'Pesaleidja (Estonia)';
```